# Reactive Extensions - Correct way to observe a Javascript call into C# wrapper

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am developing a C# WinForms application that contains a web browser control. The application contains a "scripting bridge" class that allows Javascript code to call into the web browser control (I need to know when certain functions are called in the JS code in order to perform some action in the WinForms application). Most of these operations are asynchronous because when I launch a request from the WinForms application, it will typically perform an ajax request within the JS code (not the C# code). Since this is an asynchronous operation, I was trying to come up with a better/easier way to manage the subscriptions/timeouts/error handling, etc. for these asynchronous events. I came across Reactive Extensions and decided to try it out.

I'm trying to determine if I am doing this correctly or not. I'm trying to wrap my head around Reactive Extensions. It's difficult to find simpler examples on the net for a lot of the Observable extension methods. Here is what I am doing right now:

```
public void SetupObservable()
{
    IConnectableObservable<string> javascriptResponseObservable = Observable.Create<string>(
        (IObserver<string> observer) =>
        {
            observer.OnNext("Testing");
            observer.OnCompleted();

            return Disposable.Create(() => Console.WriteLine("Observer has unsubscribed"));
        })
        .Timeout(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(5))
        .Finally(() => Console.WriteLine("Observable sequence completed"))
        .Publish();

        IObserver<string> testObserver = Observer.Create<string>(
            (value) => Console.WriteLine(value),
            (e) => Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred: " + e.Message),
            () => Console.WriteLine("Completed")
        );

    IDisposable unsubscriber = javascriptResponseObservable.Subscribe(testObserver);
}

// The following will be executed later (once the ajax request is completed)...

// Fire the event and notify all observables. If it took too long to get this point then the sequence will timeout with an exception.
public void OnSomeJavascriptFunctionCall()
{
    // Somehow get the javascriptResponseObservable object...
    javascriptResponseObservable.Connect();
}
```

I feel like I am doing this the wrong way or that there is a better way to accomplish this. For example, how do you retrieve the IObservable that was created earlier so that you can call more methods on it? Would I have to persist it in the class or somewhere else? It seems like a lot of the examples don't do this so it seems like I am doing something fundamentally wrong. Also, if several observers are subscribing to the IObservable from different classes, etc., again, how do you keep track of the IObservable? It seems like it needs to be persisted somewhere after it is created. Is there a Observable.GetExistingObservable() method of some sort that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

> I feel like I am doing this the wrong way or that there is a better way to accomplish this.

Wrong is always a point of view, but I would argue, yes there is a better way to solve what you are doing.

I assume that your JavaScript bridge has some sort of way of raising events? And this is how it is able to call-you-back? If so, they you will want to leverage that call back and bridge that to Rx using either `Observable.Create`, `Observable.FromEvent*` or another Rx factory method.

That would be your first step, then you would need to pass your "commands" to your JS layer. This is where you would need to remember to subscribe to your callback sequence before you issue the command to mitigate any race conditions.

It is difficult to help any more, as you only show Rx code that seems to serve no purpose except trying to understand Rx, and no code that shows what you are trying to achieve in the C#-to-Js bridge. Please provide a "Minimum Complete Verifiable Example" - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve